# Facebook App Website Platform URL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, url

Ive added my domain, "domain.com", as the site URL in my app settings. When i try use my website by logging onto "domain.com" the facebook features work fine. However, when logging on to "www.domain.com", facebook returns the following error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the 
given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL 
or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Comment: You can try and add the www version to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs, under Status->Advanced in your app dashboard. But perhaps you should rather make the www version of your site redirect to the non-www version automatically (or vice versa) – that is usually recommended, in terms of SEO as well (avoiding “duplicate content”).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the solution to this problem is to redirect the domain.com version to the www.domain.com to avoid this duplication issue. In order to do this in the `.htaccess` file the following was added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects any user that goes to `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`